# Dump variadic template content to a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, template-meta-programming, typelist

#### Brief description:

Consider a variadic-template based typelist used to hold integral values:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct list {};

using my_int_list = list<std::integral_constant<0>,
                         std::integral_constant<1>,
                         std::integral_constant<2>>;
```

This could be dumped to an array using array initializers and variadic pack expansion:

```
template<typename LIST>
struct to_array;

template<typename... Ts>
struct to_array<list<Ts...>>
{
    static constexpr unsigned int result[] = { Ts::value... };
};
```

Now consider I want to do the same thing with 2d arrays (In other words, the input is a typelist of typelists). We could use the later metafunction to dump subarrays, and a second metafunction to dump the outer array:

```
template<typename LIST>
struct to_2d_array;

template<typename... Ts>
struct to_2d_array<list<Ts...>>
{
    using value_type = unsigned int; //To simplify things, suppose we know the type
                                     //of the elements. Also suppose the array is 
                                     //squared.

    static constexpr value_type result[sizeof...(Ts)][sizeof...(Ts)] = { to_array<Ts>::result... };
};
```

#### My problem (i.e. context in depth):

I'm writting a compile-time Mandelbrot fractal render. The render works "fine"<sup>1</sup>, and it returns  the result as a square 2d typelist (Typelist of typelists of the same length) of RGB values. 
The `to_2d_array` metafunction is needed to dump the result to an array and write it in a PPM file at runtime.

[The RGB values](https://github.com/Manu343726/Turbo/blob/master/color.hpp) are instances of an integral wrapper equivalent to `std::integral_constant<unsigned int>`, it has a member `value` which holds the value.

The code I posted above is exactly what I have written [in my implementation](https://github.com/Manu343726/Turbo/blob/master/mandelbrot.hpp), using standard types (`std::integral_constant`) instead of my own types. The code above works perfectly [at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b89b73cf35a4a6d), but my compiler (GCC4.8.1) says:

> The initializer needs to be enclosed with an additional encloser-brace.

in `to_2d_array`. If I put the extra braces, the assigment compilation fails with a "invalid cast from pointer to array".

**What I'm doing wrong? Is there another approximation to achieve this?**

*[1] Really it isn't working now, because the compilation of this template-metaprogramming monster leads to a GCC internal segmentation fault :). But this problem is not related to the question...*

Comment: You show us the code that works, but you don't show the code that *doesn't* work. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: @DanielFrey the code I have provided is exactly the same, but using types of the standard library (i.e. types which everybody knows) instead of my own types.

Comment: @DanielFrey you could also check the original code [here](https://github.com/Manu343726/Turbo/blob/master/mandelbrot.hpp) (Line  64 and bellow)

Comment: It seems to work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0d94d5f1f915ae6)

Comment: @DanielFrey have you tried it with 2d typelists? In that example you have used a 1d typelist

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean. But just a guess: Have you tried `= { {dump_sub_array<Ts>::result}... };`? (note the different position of the `...`)

Comment: @DanielFrey thanks, but results in the same error. I mean a typelist of typelists. Try with `list<my_uint_list,my_uint_list,my_uint_list>`

Comment: That also [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/189c19bb780c109c). You need to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), otherwise I don't think anyone can really understand what your problem is. (Since it's 2am here, I'm going to bed now)

Comment: @DanielFrey very appreciated help, thanks. I will edit the question tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what's written in your [coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b89b73cf35a4a6d), There are a few problems I'd like to point out.

1. The types of `result`.

   The following code does not compile.

   ```
   int main() {
     int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
     int y[3][3] = {x, x, x};
   }
   ```

   whereas the following does.

   ```
   #include <array>

   int main() {
     std::array<int, 3> x = {1, 2, 3};
     std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> y = {x, x, x};
   }
   ```

   The types of `result` in `to_array<>` and `to_2d_array<>` is equivalent to the first example.
2. The `result` is declared as `static constexpr`, but the out-of-line definition is missing.

The following is the code with modifications made to fix the issues addressed above.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts>
struct list {};

template <typename List>
struct to_array;

template <typename... Ts>
struct to_array<list<Ts...>> {

    using result_type = std::array<unsigned int, sizeof...(Ts)>;

    /* Use std::array<> instead of C-array. */
    static constexpr result_type result = { Ts::value... };

};  // ToArray<List<Ts...>>

/* Out-of-line definition for static constexpr variable. */    
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr typename to_array<list<Ts...>>::result_type
    to_array<list<Ts...>>::result;

template <typename List>
struct to_2d_array;

template <typename... Ts>
struct to_2d_array<list<Ts...>> {

    using result_type = 
        std::array<std::array<unsigned int, sizeof...(Ts)>, sizeof...(Ts)>;

    /* Use std::array<> instead of C-array. */
    static constexpr result_type result = { to_array<Ts>::result... };
};

/* Out-of-line definition for static constexpr variable. */
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr typename to_2d_array<list<Ts...>>::result_type 
    to_2d_array<list<Ts...>>::result;

int main() {
  using my_int_list = list<std::integral_constant<int, 0>,
                           std::integral_constant<int, 1>,
                           std::integral_constant<int, 2>>;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    std::cout << to_array<my_int_list>::result[i] << ' ';
  }  // for
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
  using my_2d_list = list<my_int_list,my_int_list,my_int_list>;
  /* Actually try printing the result. */
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      std::cout << to_2d_array<my_2d_list>::result[i][j] << ' ';
    }  // for
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }  // for
}
```

Prints:

```
0 1 2

0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

Tested with gcc 4.8.2, clang 3.3 and whichever gcc 4.8 is on Coliru.